# Looking for a quick way to prove a matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It's quite simple, it takes two seconds to understand it, but I can't find a quick demonstration. Let's say I have three matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$. The matrices $A$ and $B$ *do not* commute with one other, but $C$ commutes with both.

Does this imply that $C$ must be proportional to the identity?

**EDIT**

The matrices $A$ and $B$ are supposed invertible.

Comment: Nope, not even when $C$ is invertible. For counterexample, just add $I$ to $A,B,C$ in wasting_chalk's answer.

Comment: And if $[A,B] = AB - BA$ is invertible?

Comment: What I have in mind is a bit more precise, if you look at a certain 3*3 matrix C, which commutes with any element of SO(3) it needs to be proportional to the identity.

Comment: So you need to make another edit. You need $A^{\top}A = B^{\top}B = I$ and $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$.

Comment: What is true for sure is: if $C$ commutes with every matrix, then it is scalar. This can be strengthened a bit: if $C$ commutes with every invertible matrix of determinant $1$, then it is scalar. I don't know how much further we can go this way, I admit.

Comment: Nowhere further, I thought that it would exist a demonstration of that no longer than a few lines.

Comment: The statement is again false even when one assume $[A,B]$ is invertible. I just can't find an example within $SO(3)$.

Answer (score 5):

I think the claim is not true. Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1 &0&0\\0 &1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0 &0&0\\1 &1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}0&0 &0&0\\0 &0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
C is not a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: **+1**: Your counter example works, I've tried it. $AB \neq BA$ while $AC=CA$ and $BC=CB$, as required.

Comment: Yes you're right I should have added that A and B are invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for an example with $A,B\in SO(3)$ in the comments. Let $r=1/\sqrt{2}$,
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&-1\\&&-1\end{pmatrix},
\ B=\begin{pmatrix}r&r&0\\-r&r&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},
\ C=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\\&&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $A,B\in SO(3)$ and $C$ is not a multiple of $I$. One can verify that $AC-CA=BC-CB=0$ but $AB-BA=\begin{pmatrix}0&\sqrt{2}&0\\ \sqrt{2}&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\not=0.$

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a problem similar to yours. 
What you want to prove can be proved using Schur's Lemma.
 If A is a complex matrix of order n that commutes with all matrices from G then A is a scalar matrix. If G is not irreducible, then this is not true.
We can see that all the counter examples are wrong.
First of all we can see that one of them is not irreducible and the one that "proves" it using SO(3) elements forgot that that you have to prove that C commutes with ALL SO(3) matrices, which is not true.

Hope this helps.